# I need to get 32 bit qt libs

Tags: qt, gcc, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

Is there a quick way to obtain a set of 32 bit qt libraries?  I need to put them on my 64 bit ubuntu os which already has qt installed (64 bits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the generic source, then run `configure` with the following option:

```
./configure --platform=linux-g++-32
```

Comment: I got the source for qt but I got the following error:  linux-g++-32: unknown argument

   The specified system/compiler is not supported:

      /home/yan/qtSource3/mkspecs/yes

Comment: `qtSource3` seems to imply that's Qt-3? Is a linux-g++-32 bit folder present in the mkspecs directory?

Comment: yes the folder is present and no it is not it is not qt3, I simply called it like that, I had more than one folder of qt source

Comment: Do you have the `*-multilb` packages installed for gcc?

Comment: It wasnt installed. did a sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib and now it works thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

According to the content listing at http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/ia32-libs it contains 32bit QT.

Comment: says it is already installed....actually im trying to create a 32 bit executable to send on a RHEL 5 x86_32.  Im gonna build it on ubuntu 64 karmic then send him the executable alog with the qt libs

Comment: You'll need to verify that you don't have a higher version of glibc, and then confirm that your version of Qt isn't compiled against something not present on his, such as `XFixes` which isn't present on older systems. Providing binaries is nice, but it's also somewhat of an art form.

Comment: You are right, it is alot more complexe than just installing the 32 bit version of qt.  I was successfull in providing 64 bit binaries to multiple linux distros that are also 64 bit but now this adds another obstacle to my goal. I will probably just use a vm machine if i dont get this resolved soon.